# Physics engine deltaTime and force acceleration

Tags: physics, game-loop, timestep

I am working on a physics engine that uses basic Euler integration to compute forces. So, here is the thing:

```
function applyForce (rigidbody, force) { 
    rigidbody.forces.add(force);
}

function computeAcceleration (rigidbody) {
    rigidbody.acceleration = rigidbody.forces / mass; 
    rigidbody.velocity = rigidbody.velocity + rigidbody.acceleration * time.deltaTime;
}

// The forces are reset after each gameloop
```

So now imagine I want to apply a force to jump, I will use `applyForce` at the moment the player presses the jump button.

But: What happens is that the amount of movement depends on the gameloop speed, since the force is applied for a single frame. I feel like I missed something about how you should use forces, but I don't see how I should manage it properly.

In which cases should we use a force, considering this deltaTime issue? And also, what should I use instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s because, in general, jumping involves applying an [impulse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_%28physics%29) instead of a [force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force).

You apply forces when the interaction is expected to last for at least some time. For instance, gravity is a force: it lasts more or less forever. Pushing a door is applying a force, too: you keep pushing while the door opens.

You apply impulses when the interaction should be more or less immediate. Jumping, or hitting a ball with a bat: this involves impulses. Everything happens in a very short timespan.

This is how you could modify your code in order to apply impulses in addition to forces:

```
function applyForce (rigidbody, force) { 
    rigidbody.forces.add(force); // This is still valid, but not for jumping
}

function applyImpulse (rigidbody, impulse) { 
    rigidbody.impulse.add(impulse);
}

function computeAcceleration (rigidbody) {
    rigidbody.acceleration = rigidbody.forces / mass; // This is still valid
    rigidbody.velocity = rigidbody.velocity
                       + rigidbody.impulses / mass
                       + rigidbody.acceleration * time.deltaTime;
}
```

Of course, as suggested by MickLH, you should probably use Verlet integration instead of Euler (by averaging the previous velocity and the new velocity), too. But the main problem you have is forces *vs.* impulses.

Comment: Impulses do seem like the correct way to go, although your example seems weird to me. Shouldn't the impulse just add to the current velocity? I tried this way but it gives results depending on time. What I did is just when an impulse is applied, add it to the velocity

Comment: Oh, you’re absolutely right. I wrote `* deltaTime` instead of `/ deltaTime`, sorry for the confusion. Adding to the velocity is correct.

Comment: Yep. And you added the mass, I initially forgot to take it into account in my original version of the impulses. Anyway this one is good and everything works well now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The fix is simple, integrate position in the *middle* of integrating velocity. (As in, add half of the force, update, then add the other half.)

Here is a more in-depth explanation: http://www.niksula.hut.fi/~hkankaan/Homepages/gravity.html

Comment: Oh that's a great answer thanks! I'll implement this now to see if it's better.

Comment: This fix is really good. It have allowed to me that I wrote a precise prediction for the jumps of my characters.

Comment: The link is dead.  Fix it .